# How to loop XMLHttpRequest in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, loops, xmlhttprequest

I have created a random word app using an API from setgetgo.com. My problem is after, the "fetch random word" button is pressed, the iteration is complete. I want to the user to get a random word each time they click the button instead of clicking the "start over" button I built. I've searched for answers on how to put the api call into a loop but am turning up nothing.

I've tried placing the entire block of code in a form loop, (for (var i=0; i<[the function].length; i++), I've tried setting it at the end of the code to execute again, and I've also tried nesting it inside the "loadText" function. Each way I try it it doesn't go for me.

Here's my javascript code:

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

//GET A RANDOM WORD//
ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://setgetgo.com/randomword/get.php');

var word = ourRequest.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', loadText);
    function loadText(){
        document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = ourRequest.responseText;
    }
};

ourRequest.send();
```

Any ideas, Stack Overflow friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the API on each click, like this:

```
function loadWord() {
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://setgetgo.com/randomword/get.php');
    ourRequest.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = ourRequest.responseText;
    };
    ourRequest.send();
}

document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', loadWord);
```

Comment: you've made my day! Thank you soooo very much!

Comment: No problem mate :] Will be glad if you accept/upvote my answer :]

Comment: I would love to, but how do I do that? Sorry, I'm a tad bit new here.

Nevermind, I think I found it.